# Two UDTs to insert values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following scenario.

PFB my query

```
DECLARE @termlength AS Prdctlg.ContractTermLengthType;

DECLARE @PromotionIdsTable AS Prdctlg.PromotionsType

INSERT INTO @termlength (PromotionName,
PromotionStartDate,
PromotionEndDate,
PromotionDescription,
TermLengthPrice,
LengthInMonths)
  VALUES ('CT1', '02/02/2017', '02/02/2019', 'Desc', '12', '15')

INSERT INTO @termlength (PromotionName,
PromotionStartDate,
PromotionEndDate,
PromotionDescription,
TermLengthPrice,
LengthInMonths)
  VALUES ('CT12', '02/02/2017', '02/02/2018', 'Desc13', '122', '152')

INSERT INTO PrdCtlg.Promotions (PromotionName, PromotionStartDate, PromotionEndDate, PromotionTypeId)
OUTPUT INSERTED.pkPromotionsId INTO @PromotionIdsTable (PromotionsId)
  SELECT
    PromotionName,
    PromotionStartDate,
    PromotionEndDate,
    1
  FROM @termlength


SELECT
  *
FROM @PromotionIdsTable
SELECT
  *
FROM @termlength
```

I want to insert these values of @PromotionIdsTable UDT in @termlength TermLengthId. Is there any posibility

Comment: Please, show us your attempt and sample data

Comment: Do you mean: the *same* `PromotionsId` but different `PromotionDescription`?

Comment: which row to delete? you need to decide which row is the correct one

Comment: It looks like you have replicated information for each `PromotionsId`, and you want to mix things up a bit and return one unique record for each of the Promotions... correct? This seems like a random requirement. Either you want data for a given promotion, or you want the promotions which cover a given promotion description... The mixup you say you want seems to make no sense.

Comment: Please check the edited question

Comment: @Sana  Variable Table termlength  AND PromotionIdsTable you had not mention as a table then how can you insert value in it.

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed these are two udts i need to insert thir merged rows in a table

Comment: @Sana why don't you try Union ALL and insert the The Rows in Another Table

Comment: @Sana Check my answer, here is your desired outputs, you can accept the answer if it works for you. I was answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46442832/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (PromotionsId INT, PromotionDescription NVARCHAR(50), TermLengthPrice MONEY);
/**/
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(3168, 'Desc', 12),
(3168, 'Desc 13', 122),
(3169, 'Desc', 12),
(3169, 'Desc 13', 122),

(3170, 'Asc', 12),
(3170, 'Asc 13', 122),
(3171, 'Asc', 12),
(3171, 'Asc 13', 122);

WITH C1 AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PromotionDescription ORDER BY PromotionDescription) AS RN
FROM @T
    )
    , 
    C2 AS
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PromotionDescription ORDER BY PromotionDescription) AS RN
        FROM @T
        )
        , FinalTable AS(
        SELECT *
        FROM C1 
        WHERE RN = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *
        FROM C2
        WHERE RN=1)
        SELECT DISTINCT PromotionsId, PromotionDescription, TermLengthPrice
        FROM FinalTable;
```

Result:

```
+==============+======================+=================+
| PromotionsId | PromotionDescription | TermLengthPrice |
+==============+======================+=================+
|         3168 | Desc                 |         12,0000 |
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|         3169 | Desc 13              |        122,0000 |
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|         3170 | Asc                  |         12,0000 |
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|         3171 | Asc 13               |        122,0000 |
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This is for the constant four rows result. Doesnt work if i have 6/8 results

Comment: but thanks its directing me somewhere

Comment: @Sana See my updates with more rows please.

Comment: @Sana Glad to help :).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO PrdCtlg.Promotions (PromotionName, PromotionStartDate, PromotionEndDate, PromotionTypeId)
SELECT PromotionName,PromotionStartDate,PromotionEndDate,PromotionDescription,TermLengthPrice,LengthInMonths
FROM @PromotionIdsTable  UNION ALL
SELECT PromotionName,PromotionStartDate,PromotionEndDate,PromotionDescription,TermLengthPrice,LengthInMonths
FROM @termlength
```